# Stuck on writing a polymorphic transpose function that accepts and returns RDDs of either Arrays or Seqs/Vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types, type-inference

I am refactoring a Scala library that interfaces with Spark to use Vectors where it makes sense. I would like to provide functions that interface directly with Spark the ability to work with either Arrays or Vectors. One of these functions is a transpose function. Yet I cannot seem to get the type signature right to make the type inference work.

I have tried defining the function signature in the following way, but this does not seem to work, instead giving me the below message about type inference when I run a test with String Vector RDDs as an example.

```
 def transpose[T, Abs <: IndexedSeq[T] : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[Abs]): RDD[Abs] = {
​
  rdd
   .zipWithIndex // give the columns an index
   .flatMap{
    case (row, row_idx) => row.zipWithIndex.map{ // give the rows an index
     case (el, col_idx) => (col_idx, (row_idx, el)) // each element now has a column and row index
    }
   }
   .groupBy(_._1)
   .sortBy(_._1)
   .map{ case (_, els) => els.map(_._2).toIndexedSeq.sortBy(_._1) }
   .map( row => row.map(_._2))
   .map(_.asInstanceOf[Abs])
 }
```

```
Error:(26, 5) inferred type arguments [Nothing,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]] do not conform to method transpose's type parameter bounds [T,Abs <: IndexedSeq[T]]
    transpose(subset)
Error:(26, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Abs]
    transpose(subset)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only manages to infer type parameters which appear in the value parameter list (or return type, in some cases). A trick that usually works in cases like this is the following:

```
def transpose[T, Abs <: IndexedSeq[T] : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[Abs with IndexedSeq[T]]): RDD[Abs] = {
  rdd
   .zipWithIndex // give the columns an index
   .flatMap{
    case (row, row_idx) => row.zipWithIndex.map{ // give the rows an index
     case (el, col_idx) => (col_idx, (row_idx, el)) // each element now has a column and row index
    }
   }
   .groupBy(_._1)
   .sortBy(_._1)
   .map{ case (_, els) => els.map(_._2).toIndexedSeq.sortBy(_._1) }
   .map( row => row.map(_._2))
   .map(_.asInstanceOf[Abs])
 }
```

Since `Abs` is a subtype of `IndexedSeq[T]`, `Abs with IndexedSeq[T]` and `Abs` are more or less equivalent(*), only now the compiler can infer that `Abs` is `Vector[String]` and `T` is `String`.

*You can actually verify this:

```
scala> implicitly[Vector[String] =:= (Vector[String] with IndexedSeq[String])]
res3: =:=[Vector[String],Vector[String] with scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]] = <function1>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely for Vectors, but Arrays apparently do not conform to the expected method signature. My understanding is that there is an implicit conversion from an Array to a subtype of Seq in Predefs, but it does not appear to apply here. I have also attempted to add an implicit parameter to the function to try and hint the compiler at this (`(implicit conv: Abs => Seq[T])` and change IndexedSeq to Seq in the function signature), but this still does not conform to the methods parameter bounds.